How to use CloneTree(root) in ListView while keeping references?
I am using Unity's UI Toolkit to create a ListView with the following code:
listView.makeItem = () =>
{
    var card = cardTemplate.CloneTree();

    var gameData = new GameData
    {
        monsternameLabel = card.Q<Label>("MonserName"),
        monsterDescriptionLabel = card.Q<Label>("MonsterDescription")
    };

    card.gameData = gameData;

    return card;
};

I tried using CloneTree(root) but I lose the reference to card. How can I keep the reference to card while using CloneTree(root)?
I want to increase ListView scroll speed with this method
:root {
--unity-metrics-single_line-height: 500px;
}

but it is not working.
I tried everything on this Unity Discussion
So i think it might be not working because of the warning on Unity Doc.

Important: When you use CloneTree() without a parameter or Instantiate(), it adds a TemplateContainer that stops the line height from propagating. Use CloneTree(root) instead.
Unity ScrollView Doc

But i could not figure out a correct way to use CloneTree with root parameter.
ps.
I tried mouseWheelScrollSize, and it works on the computer but not on Android.
